# Conditional sorting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table of conferences that have the following relevant fields:

1. Conference name (text)
2. Submission deadline (date)
3. Notification date (date)
4. Event start (date)
5. Event end (date)

I would like to like to query all conferences where the event end is greater than, say, today, and *order* them as follows:

1. First, all conferences where the notification is in the future; order these by notification date.
2. *Then*, all conferences where the notification is in the past; order these by event start.

I have tried:

```
(SELECT * FROM conferences
 WHERE ev_end >= '2014-06-30'
 AND notification >= '2014-06-30'
 ORDER BY notification ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM conferences
 WHERE ev_end >= '2014-06-30'
 AND notification < '2014-06-30'
 ORDER BY ev_start ASC);
```

But it does not work, the ordering is incorrect. In fact, I can discern no ordering at all: When I leave out the two `ORDER BY` clauses, the result is ordered in exactly the same way (i.e., looks random).

Is it possible to achieve this with *one single* SQL query? Or do I have to make two separate queries?

I am aware of this question: [Conditional sorting in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084362/conditional-sorting-in-mysql), but my case is completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a single query by putting all the logic in the `order by` clause:

```
select *
from conferences
where ev_end >= '2014-06-30' 
order by (notification >= '2014-06-30') desc,
         (case when notification >= '2014-06-30' then notification end) asc,
         (case when notification < '2014-06-30' then ev_start end) asc;
```

Note that `union` explicitly does not guarantee the order of the result set.  If you want the result set in a particular order, then you want an `order by` in the outermost part of the query.

Comment: I think you have to remove `and` before `order by` clause

Comment: Thanks, this worked (just as @Vatev's solution). I chose to accept your answer because you added some explanations. Could you also explain the `order by (notification >= '2014-06-30')` part? What does this do?

Comment: `(notification >= '2014-06-30')` evaluates to 1 or 0, it orders those values.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa . . . In MySQL, a boolean expression is treated as an integer, with "true" being `1` and "false" being `0`.  So that expression is shorthand for `case when notification >= '2014-06-30' then 1 else 0 end) desc`, putting the matching rows first, followed by the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM conferences
WHERE ...
ORDER BY notification < '2014-06-30', 
         IF(notification < '2014-06-30', ev_start, notification)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM conferences
WHERE ev_end >= '2014-06-30'
ORDER BY IF(notification >= '2014-06-30', notification, ev_start) ASC
```

And IF is used to return either notification or ev_start as the value to sort on, depending on whether notification is in the future

Comment: This will not work as it only returns conferences whose notification is in the past (`AND notification < '2014-06-30'`), so the `IF` clause will always evaluate to `FALSE`, and I miss all conferences whose notification date is in the future.

Comment: Actually, this still isn't exactly what I wanted, as this will not put all conferences with notifications in the future above all conferences with notifications in the past. There should be another `(notification >= '2014-06-30') DESC,` between the `ORDER BY` and the `IF` clauses.