# Using case in mysql ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table consisting of: items, a ranking score and the number of votes a user has cast on it. For simplicity: id, ranks, votes.

I'm trying to run a query which sorts items from highest ranking score to lowest, unless the number of votes = 0.

Because I have a base ranking score for new items, ordering my ranking isn't possible.

I've tried the following, along with some other permutations:

```
$list = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM ranks ORDER BY votes desc, rating desc case when min(votes)= 0 else rating desc');
```

to no avail, after looking at :
[Conditional sorting in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489100/conditional-sorting-in-mysql) and
[Conditional sorting in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084362/conditional-sorting-in-mysql)

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM ranks ORDER BY rating desc, case votes when 0 then votes end
```

This is the table, and the output I get:

```
ID : Rating : Votes
2 : 201 : 9
3 : 100 : 0
4 : 100 : 0
5 : 100 : 0
1 : -13 : 9
```

My ideal output would be:

```
ID : Rating : Votes
2 : 201 : 9
1 : -13 : 9
4 : 100 : 0
5 : 100 : 0
3 : 100 : 0
```

As you can see, this doesn't group all the 0 voted items to the end.

I'm sure this is forehead slappingly simple, I'd really appreciate any pointers and best practices. Cheers!

Comment: Please provide a sample table and output or simply create a fiddle.

Comment: Where do the rows with `votes=0` go? At the end of the list?

Comment: thanks right, I added some example tables as suggested by @Ullas and to clarify question

Comment: @alireza you got it, at the end

Comment: @matt your vote column values of expected  output differs from the sample data set same for Rating column too

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid good spot, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * 
FROM ranks 
ORDER BY case votes 
WHEN 0 THEN 0 
ELSE 1 END DESC, rating DESC
```

What the ORDER BY section is saying is:

- for the SELECT query, when the votes = 0 (an item has no votes), then
  mySQL will consider the number of votes as 0.
- ELSE - for all other numbers of votes, consider the number of votes = 1.
- END - ends the 'case'
- DESC - order the our newly considered votes (0 or 1) from highest to lowest. i.e. group the 1's at the top.
- Rating DESC - the secondary ordering condition, within the primary ordering condition, order from highest rating to lowest.

Comment: Could you explain in laymans English for me, what the "case votes when 0..." section means. This works perfectly, but my small grey matter is struggling

Comment: the `case` expression returns a single result for each of the conditions. `case x when a then b when c then d else e end` will return b when `x=a`, d when `x=c` and e when x is none of the above.

Comment: As for our query, we need all the rows with `votes=0` move to the end of the result set and all the other rows ordered based on rating. So we `normalize` the votes column: we create an expression that equals to 1 for all rows with `votes <> 0` in order to keep them at the top and 0 for rows with `votes = 0` in order to move  them to the end.

Comment: and the rest should be simple. Based on the order of expressions in the `order by` clause, rows are first sorted based on the `case` expression we just created: all rows with `votes=1` on top. Then the next expression will be applied and re-order these ordered rows but respecting the order with more priority

Comment: I don't really know my writing falls into `laymans English` or not, but at least I tried! ;-)

Comment: that really helps! I'm going to edit your answer so it contains a fuller explanation for anyone else who stumbled upon this question. Feel free to check what i write to make sure I haven't butchered it!

Answer (score 5):

This group all 0's to end.

```
SELECT * FROM `ranks` ORDER BY (Votes=0), Rating DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need case a simple order by will do the job

```
SELECT * FROM ranks 
ORDER BY Votes DESC,Rating desc
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25d43/2)

Comment: This works for my current example, but it always prioritizes votes, rather than ratings (unless there are 0 votes). Really appreciate you working on this.